# Swift 2.3 Use of unresolved identifier Firebase 'FIR' after pod update

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, cocoapods, updates

Using Xcode 8 and Swift 2.3 and using Firebase in my project
I just did pod update and getting so many errors and not able to figure out why?

If This error is because of the update, How to revert to the previous version?

Pod File

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
```

Just did pod update and got below

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using Firebase (4.1.0)
Using FirebaseAnalytics (4.0.3)
Using FirebaseCore (4.0.5)
Using FirebaseInstanceID (2.0.1)
Using FirebaseMessaging (2.0.1)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 3 dependencies from the Podfile and 9 total pods installed.
```

I am getting all below error:

```
Use of undeclared type 'FIRMessagingDelegate'
Use of unresolved identifier 'FIRApp'
Use of unresolved identifier 'kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification'
Use of unresolved identifier 'FIRMessaging'
Use of unresolved identifier 'FIRInstanceID'
Use of undeclared type 'FIRMessagingRemoteMessage'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasemessaging/api/reference/Classes/FIRMessaging), class names changes for Firebase 4.0.0 in Swift. So `FIRMessagingDelegate`, is now `MessagingDelegate`, and so on. See the migration guide [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/naming-migration-guide)

Comment: Thanks your answer really helped me a lot.
Can u consider voting up for my questions too? So it wil come up and help others also who face problem like me